# If the blindfold on a healthy old man that was never removed since birth is taken down, would the man recognize what he saw?

Tags: brain, vision, senses, illusion

I know our brain somehow managed to upright the inverted images our eyes sees, also there's tons of optical illusions out there that are based on what we knew and experienced. Then if those so called calibration were never existed in the first place... would the old man sees any optical illusion for the first time when his blindfold is removed? Also can technology be used to recalibrate our brain to see through all optical illusions?

Comment: Is this worldbuilding or philosophy? In other words, it seems like you are prompting a discussion, not looking for a solution to a worldbuilding problem

Comment: This is more of a neuroscience question, one for which Hubel and Wiesel won a Nobel Prize, but doesn't seem on topic for the Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: It strikes me that it would be relatively simple to re-write this slightly, add the [tag:reality-check] tag and make it on topic.

Comment: downvoted for obvious flaws of premise, which current answer clarify why, but sure the q has nothing to do with philosophy, and in my opinion it perfectly on topic. Having proper answer on nature of illusion and how technology could help there - for sure would improve quality of someone's work. And as part, or a subset of augmented reality topics it can potentially be reused by other authors. Technology can help, but it is not 100% foolproof. I mean if a magician throws a ball out of his hand behind his back  - the illusion here is not what you see or do not see - but what you assume.

Comment: @L.Dutch This question relates to the fields of experimental psychology, neuroscience, and biology. It has very little relation with philosophy. [Optical illusions were studied extensively by psychologists and neuroscientists.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=optical+illusions&btnG=&oq=optical+ill)

Comment: @user6760 Do you want to handwave the effects of a blindfold? The answer by Mon is correct, an old man who used to wear a blindfold for his entire life will be functionally blind. I have a feeling, though, that this answer is not very useful to you.

Comment: Voted to close, but more because it includes two very different questions in one. The first one (removing the blindfold) seems off-topic since it's purely medical, psychological and/or neurobiology. In its current state, that is. The second one (technology to remove illusions) is much more on-topic, but it's not the same thing as "what if I lost my blindness"!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the person would be functionally blind. Experiments have already been conducted with animals (dogs) EDIT: as I was reminded it was CATS raised from birth in visually deprived environments that prove the visual cortex needs exposure to stimulus in order to grow, develop and function normally like all other parts of the brain. Deprive it of that stimulus and the brain will divert resources to other senses in order to compensate. 2nd EDIT: depending on how long the 'old' man lived there might be some improvement in visual acuity but it is still extremely unlikely the man would 'see' anywhere near normally before he died.

Comment: Wasn't it kittens?  IIRC, Hubel and Wiesel were the first and others followed, e.g. https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/brain-food/201404/the-cat-nobel-prize-part-ii

Comment: Yes, you could be right. I couldn't remember the details after reading about it at Uni. As I recall (and correct me if I am wring ) it was two sets plus a control of (insert favorite small fluffy pet here) raised in sealed rooms with either vertical stripes or horizontal stripes as the only visual cues. The animals raised in the 'vertical' room couldn't process/see horizontal visual cues and vice versa.  And neither set was capable of visually navigating 'normal' environments.  Imagine trying to justify reintroducing that experiment now!

Comment: with a link and some excerpts from it, it could be a perfect answer about flaws of the premise(and partially an answer due to that)

Comment: I second this. One of my course books in college spoke about this very subject, where a man was born blind but modern technology restored his vision as an adult. At one point when he was still on the 7th floor in the hospital recovering from the procedure a nurse found him hanging out the window trying to reach down to touch the cars driving by on the street (they quickly pulled him away from the window). Because he wasn't used to having vision he often didn't know what he was looking at, and couldn't do a lot of things like determine how far away objects are that he saw.